# Android studio preview gets disappeared when NestedScrollView added to XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

My Android Studio version is 1.3 (Stable Channel). When I add `<android.support.v4.NestedScrollView>` to my XML layouts, the preview of Android Studio disappears from the right side, and the design tab too.

Also when I want to add a new view to the XML I don't see some of external library views, which are available to add, in the suggestion dialog. For example I can't see `android.support.v4.NestedScrollview` but `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` is available to choose.
[image: support libraries shown]
[image: when I start to type Nested...]

I have added these lines to my apps's dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
```

Comment: same issue I also encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Android Studio that should have been fixed (at least in 1.5, which is available in canary/beta channels). The bug was that when there was an exception during rendering the preview, it was mistakenly hidden in certain cases.

If you still see the issue in 1.5, please file a bug using the instructions at http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: You are right. I saw the bug in the list in the past and now it is gone and the life is easier.